# Is the procedure correct for generating Sequence number in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Please check if the following procedure is correct? Insertion not happening.

I want to generate sequence number in first column. Please let me know if it is correct.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_JCP_SET_DET_BND_LST(  
    p_channel IN VARCHAR2,   
    p_deptBrandListName IN VARCHAR2,  
    p_groupNo IN NUMBER,
    p_userID IN VARCHAR2
    )
AS
  SequenceId          NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT seqid1+1 into SequenceId from(SELECT CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST_ID as seqid1 
FROM GMPPFC.CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST
ORDER  BY CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST_ID DESC) where rownum=1;

INSERT INTO GMPPFC.CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST
(
CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST_ID,
CHANNEL_NM,
DEPT_BRAND_LIST_NM,
GROUP_NO,
CREATE_USER_ID,
CREATE_TS,
CHANGE_USER_ID,
CHANGE_TS)
VALUES
(
SequenceId, 
p_channel,
p_deptBrandListName,
p_groupNo,
p_UserID,
sysdate,
null,
null
);

COMMIT;
NULL;
END SP_JCP_SET_DET_BND_LST;
```

Comment: Why don't you use Oracle sequences? (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)

Comment: BTW your query could have problems with an empty table, I usually use "...SELECT MAX(NVL(SequenceId ,0)) + 1 ..." (when not using sequences)

Comment: @Maxx - don't you mean `NVL(MAX(SequenceId), 0)` ?

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes, you're right (the opposite doesn't work with an empty table)

Answer (score 2):

In principle it will work provided your table is not empty as commented by Maxx.

However, a proper implementation would be to use a sequence and for such plain case consider a trigger.

It would be this one:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_SEQ START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BIR_CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST
    BEFORE INSERT ON CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_LIST_ID := CHANNEL_DEPT_BRAND_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    :NEW.CREATE_TS := SYSDATE;
END;
/
```

Your solution will create problems in a multi-user environment when several sessions call your procedure at the same time.